# File -> New -> Titanium Desktop Application Not Shown - Titanium Help Needed

Tags: titanium, desktop-application

I have installed titanium in ubuntu 11.10.i want  to create desktop application
but I dont know what tools,API,SDK is required and how to configure all the SDK,API
and tools in titanium. So give all the step to required configuration of titanium
to create desktop application...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Titanium Desktop is no longer mantained by Appcelerator.

You can check here for the Desktop SDK which is community mantained: http://tidesdk.org/

Comment: I appreciate your response and i have already gone through it but did not find proper help on tidesdk. Does it work in collaboration with titanium or its a different system?

Comment: Have you checked this help page? http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started
It explains how to get started step by step.

Comment: THanks! i am just doing it.

Comment: steps failed again. I have two iMAC in my older i find file->new->Cretae Titanium Desktop Application option running titanium v 1.7.2. But in other app i dont find.

Comment: What is that thing that you cannot find? The dropdown menu for selecting the sdk version?
Have you checked that you have installed the sdk in its proper location?

Comment: Hi, we succesfully installed and created desktop app using TideSdk with your help, but we don't find any way to edit the project or where we can write the code. Can we write the code in Titanium Studio? Please help!

Comment: You can write in any text editor, it can be Titanium Studio or any other of your choice. If you choose a different from Titanium Studio, be sure it uses UTF-8 encoding, otherwise you might have problems when executing your application.